# How to extract year and month from date in python

Tags: python

I tried some functions but those functions cannot produce the right answer for some dates, [image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UohTA.png). Like the first date "12/11/2015", the month should be 11 instead of 12. Does anyone know how to solve this in general?

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add another argument called `dayfirst: bool`, like so:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['12/11/2015', '19/11/2015', '7/12/2015']
})

df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date'], dayfirst=True).month
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date'], dayfirst=True).year
print(df)
```

Result:

```
         date  month  year
0  12/11/2015     11  2015
1  19/11/2015     11  2015
2   7/12/2015     12  2015
```